# Regex capture not returning expected array

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to use regex to generate an array of capture groups, but the capture groups aren't capturing the strings I expect.

My input resembles the following general format:

```
S2244060800027008209302B000A667A6201A6828E1976007A000A52820009A3420009B0FE1F
```

This string has the following components:
A 4 character prefix, 3 byte address, a series of 2 byte data blocks, a 1 byte line terminator.

I only care about the address and the data blocks.

The regex I tried to use is:
`/\w{4}(\w{6})(\w{4})+/;`

(I have an inelegant solution using substrings to parse the input before performing the regex, but I hate it...)

The original non-functional code is below:

```
open IN, "<$ARGV[0]" or die "Could not open '$ARGV[0]': $!\n";
open OUT, ">$ARGV[0].txt" or die "Could not open '$ARGV[0].txt': $!\n";

while (<IN>)
{
    print OUT join(" ",/^\w{4}(\w{6})(\w{4})+/)."\n"; 
}
close IN;
close OUT;
```

My desired output is an array with the following elements:

```
@array = [406080, 0027, 0082, 0930, 2B00, 0A66, 7A62, 01A6, 828E, 1976, 007A, 000A, 5282, 0009, A342, 0009, B0FE]
```

But the preceding regex results in a two element array containing only the 3 byte address, and the last data block:

```
@array = [406080, B0FE]
```

This implies to me that i have a fundamental misunderstanding of how regex capture groups work that I would like clarified.

Here's my crappy workaround just for the sake of completeness:

```
    open IN, "<$ARGV[0]" or die "Could not open '$ARGV[0]': $!\n";    
    open OUT, ">$ARGV[0].txt" or die "Could not open '$ARGV[0].txt': $!\n";

    while (<IN>)
    {
        print OUT substr($_, 4, 6)." ".join(" ",substr($_, 10) =~ /\w{4}/g)."\n"; 
    }

    close IN;
    close OUT;
```

Comment: What happens to `S224`?

Comment: it's discarded as a non-captured match,

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quantifying a capture group doesn't create several capture groups. It matches according to the quantifier, but only the last match is captured.

[unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) is more suitable to extract parts of binary data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = 'S2244060800027008209302B000A667A6201A6828E1976007A000A52820009A3420009B0FE1F';

my $exp = [qw[ 406080 0027 0082 0930 2B00 0A66 7A62 01A6 828E 1976 007A 000A 5282 0009 A342 0009 B0FE ]];

my @result = unpack 'x4A6(A4)*', $s;
die unless '1F' eq pop @result;

use Test::More tests => 1;
is_deeply \@result, $exp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Can you clarify a few details about unpack for me?
What is the first set of parentheses buying you in the template?
Why is the last byte being captured since it doesn't appear to match the template?

Comment: Sorry, the parentheses weren't needed, they were a result of my experiments. Removed.